# How many loops? Expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a problem with this exercise. I completely do not know hot to tackle it. Please help.

A bin contains $N$ strings. You randomly choose two loose ends and
tie them up. You continue until there are no more free ends. What is the
expected number of loops you get?

Comment: is a loop tying the same string to itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since each time you reduce the total number of loose ends by 2, so you will tie exactly $N$ times.

When there are $2k$ loose ends, the chance of you making one loop is $\frac{1}{2k-1}$ (the chance of the second end you grab being from the same string of the first one you did). So adding up all of them, the expectation is:$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}$.

It's worth mentioning, when $n\to\infty$, $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\approx\ln{2n}+e-\frac{1}{2}(\ln{n}+e)=\frac{1}{2}\ln{n}+\ln{2}-\frac{1}{2}e\approx\frac{1}{2}\ln{n}+0.4$.

Here, $e$ is the Eular Constant.